# Cannot run emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

while running the emulator for the first time.It is showing like this.
I am begginer
I am using ubuntu android studio 3.1

> 4:59 PM   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 4:59 PM   Emulator: qemu-system-i386: -drive
>   if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/home/u1429652/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img,read-only:
>   Could not open
>   '/home/u1429652/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img':
>   Operation not permitted
>
> 4:59 PM   Gradle build finished in 2s 422ms
>
> 4:59 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this [Cannot launch AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094934/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator-in-android-studio-invalid-argument)
I hope this will help you to solve this issue.

Comment: But i cannot able to edit the RAM in AVD .Here My RAM is 1536 MB. VM heap is 256 MB, internal storage 2048MB and sd card studio managed 100MB.I cannot able to edit RAM and VM-heap.Please help

Comment: please help me as i am new android studio